# Multiple conditions that depend on date, result and repeated names

Tags: excel, google-sheets, array-formulas

Looking for a formula/array that will "write an "x"" in column D when the following conditions occur:

1. date is prior to date in column A
2. text is the same as in column B
3. the last value in column C is "1" (on rows that have the same name as B)

For example: If on 4.11, Eugene has a "1" in Column C, then then column D for 4.10 should have an "x", otherwise it would be blank...

As soon as Joey gets a "1" as a result, all the previous dates should become "x"... pretty much everything for Joey before the last "1" should automatically be "x".

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lhL7w411XkgZpXpBTphy1yIioVPlYfSJBRXAdTTH-4s/edit?usp=sharing

```
Date    Name    Result   Reset Fx 
4.10    Eugene  0    FALSE 
4.10    Joey    0    FALSE 
4.11    Eugene  1    x 
4.11    Joey    0    FALSE 
4.12    Joey    0    FALSE 
4.15    Joey    0    FALSE 
4.18    Joey    0    FALSE 
4.18    Joey    0    FALSE 
4.19    Joey    0    FALSE 
4.21    Joey    1    x 
4.22    Tony    0    FALSE 
4.22    Joey    0    FALSE 
4.23    Andy    0    FALSE 
4.23    Andy    0    FALSE 
4.23    Tony    0    FALSE 
4.24    Tony    0    FALSE 
4.24    Tony    0    FALSE 
4.24    Andy    0    FALSE 
4.24    Andy    1    x 
4.25    Tony    0    FALSE 
4.25    Andy    0    FALSE 
4.25    Andy    0    FALSE 
4.25    Andy    0    FALSE 
4.25    Eugene  0    FALSE 
4.25    Eugene  0    FALSE
```

I have tried arrays, if, ifs, if w and...
I get stuck trying to get the repeated name and the prior dates to get a result in a different cell.

Comment: Your three rules are vague and/or ambiguous. Would you please review and edit them as appropriate. For example #1, `4.24    Andy    1    x ` = the date in the preceding row = 4.24 so it is not a `prior` date. Example#2, `4.11    Eugene  1    x` - the name in the preceding row = "Joey" so not same as Column B. OTOH, `text is the same as in column B` may mean that the name has appeared previously in Column B, not necessarily on the preceding row.

Comment: From your sample sheet, it seems, you only put `x` for `1` in column `C`. What do you mean by `text is the same as in column B`?

Comment: Some of the names are repeated on the same date, that's the way the data is, but if the event is "true, aka "1"" for a name, it will be true for all of them on the same date.

Comment: The answer from CJJones woks on excel, but results blank on google sheets (which is what I'm using)...  and I would have to update the column as new values are added.

Comment: Using Joey as example:  on 4.10, 4.11 up to 4.19 he had "0"; but on 4.21 had "1"; ideally as soon as put that "x" next to the 1 all of the previous "0's" would also have an "x" next to it...  but not the "0" with a later date...

Comment: I don't mind adding the "x" next to the one because that happens daily, what is difficult is having to go back to find each date that they had "0's" and writing the "x"...  using the "x" removes other values from the spreadsheet and resets other counts that I have on it.

Comment: If anyone can make a formula to add the "x" next to the "1" PLUS on every "0" for that name with a prior date, well that solves the problem as well.

Comment: Also, there should not be an "x" for a name with a "0" for a date after a "1", until another "1" is noted for that name... hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You guys got me on the right track.

=iferror(if(A2<=index(filter($A$2:$A,$C$2:$C=1,$B$2:$B=$B2),sumproduct(--($C$2:C=1),--($B$2:$B=$B2))),"x",""),"")

I have to drag it down because it won't work as arrayformula, but it does what I need.
The example sheet shows the results.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the question correctly, you want column D to be x for every instance of a name before the date it is marked as `1`. I solved it assuming that `1` would only be input for only one date for each name. I used a combination of match, index, and filter to determine which date had the `1` for each name and use that date and name as a reference for the prior date. Hope this helps!

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(B2=(INDEX(FILTER($B:$B,$B:$B=B2,0),MATCH(1,FILTER($C:$C,$B:$B=B2,0),0),1)),
A2<=(INDEX(FILTER($A:$A,$B:$B=B2,0),MATCH(1,FILTER($C:$C,$B:$B=B2,0),0),1))),"x",""),"")
```

Comment: This is very close to what I need... It worked when I typed it in excel, but doesn't result when I use it in Google Sheets...

Comment: Also I think I would have to run the column again once more values are added... AKA: it's not dynamic...      I really appreciate your help, this is the closest I've gotten to not having to do this manually...  the spreadsheet has a LOT more values than what i posted.

Comment: reading your response, there will be more "1" for each name...